# Asp.Net localization of text in webservice method

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

When I want to localize code behind of page I use this

```
HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject(path, message)
```

My question is that, is there a way to use local resources of page inside webservice methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can't use `HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject` instead of that use [**`HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.getglobalresourceobject.aspx)

> **Global Resource Files**
>
> You create a global resource file by putting it in the reserved folder
>   App_GlobalResources at the root of the
>   application. Any .resx file that is in the App_GlobalResources folder
>   has global scope. Additionally, ASP.NET generates a strongly typed
>   object that gives you a simple way to programmatically access global
>   resources.

**Local Resource Files**

> **A local resources file is one that applies to only one ASP.NET page or user control** (an ASP.NET file that has a
>   file-name extension of .aspx, .ascx, or .master). You put local
>   resource files in folders that have the reserved name
>   App_LocalResources. Unlike the root App_GlobalResources folder,
>   App_LocalResources folders can be in any folder in the application.
>   You associate a set of resources files with a specific Web page by
>   using the name of the resource file.

Comment: The problem is that I have many many web methods and text to be translated. If it all going to be in one file, it would be hard to trace it out. I think Microsoft should make resource files for web services too. Any one Agree with me ? :D