# How do you read a local resource from a web method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webmethod

I have the following project structure:

[image]

My web method is declared in the file "MobileStart.cs" and I need to read a resource value from file "start.aspx.resx". Following is my attempt to read the resource value:

```
[WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public static string EmailSurveyLink(string email)
    {
        var response = new StartPageResponse();

        string message = String.Format(HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject("~/Surveys/start.aspx.resx", "LoginSentEmail", new CultureInfo("en-AU")).ToString(), messageVars);

        return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(response);
    }
```

And I am getting the following error when I call the method from client-side:

```
Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure "start.aspx.resx.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "App_LocalResources.surveys.cdcab7d2.jsl8asuu" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.
```

I would appreciate a solution thanks.

Comment: @Jumpei  Tried it but I get the same error as above

Comment: Do you need switching culture?

Comment: I get the same error even if I use the following:  string message = String.Format(HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject("~/Surveys/start.aspx.resx", "LoginSentEmail").ToString(), messageVars);

Comment: If `EmailSurveyLink` is a member of the class `MobileStart`. `string message = String.Format(this.GetLocalResourceObject("LoginSentEmail").ToString(), messageVars);`

Comment: Are the resources not statically typed on compile? Cant you reference the resource string directly? Resources.LoginSentEmail

Comment: @Moke It seems I cannot do that.

Answer (score 0):

> You can't use `HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject` instead of that use
>   `HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject`

The question has been previously answer here:

[Asp.Net localization of text in webservice method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18229650/asp-net-localization-of-text-in-webservice-method)